# How can I close discussions in SharePoint 2013 Community Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, community-site

I have been handed a requirement for a community forum intranet project I am part of. part of the spec is a retention policy which will automate closing inactive threads, retain them for a period in an 'Archive' category and then delete them after a further period.

I can find to way to close active threads so they cannot  be posted in or replied to.

Does anyone have any experience of solving a problem like this?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar requirement recently, however did not find any out of box way of doing it.

Something I did:

1. Create a new column e.g. status
2. Create a workflow to rename the title (add `[CLOSED]` to the beginning) and then modify the permission of members group to read.
   Once the status has changed to `closed`, members will not be able to reply.

If you have found any better solution, please let me know.